# How do I read CalDAV objects from Google using python/django?

Tags: python, django, icalendar

I've looked at `vObject`, `iCalendar`, and the official list of `CalDAV` libraries, including [3 in python](http://caldav.calconnect.org/implementations/librariestools.html). However, I can't find any code that can get me an event object from a given `CalDAV` (i.e. google, exchange, etc.) server using a username/password. Most of the `Django` calendar-related code uses native code libraries and not `WebDAV`.

An ideal Python `CalDAV` client example would

1. Use a given `uid/pw`,
2. Obtain primary calendar and
3. Obtain next appointment information (i.e. subject, location, start, end, etc.)

Comment: No, an ideal library would not obtain next appointment information. It would obtain *all* appointment information in some way.

Maybe if you explained why you can not do this, you might get an answer, because to my knowledge, that's exactly what these libraries do. You typically use CalDAV to obtain iCalendar info, and use an iCalendar library to parse that into event objects.